# How to update a field-List in MongoDB using Mongoose and Nodehs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Hello dear Stackoverflow team.

I am trying to patch a user, which can handle several "devices". I am using nodeJs with Express and Mongoose (MongoDB). My User model is the following:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
     name: {type: String, required: true},
     lastname: {type: String, required: true},
     email: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true, unique: 
            true},
     password: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5},
     userTyp: {type: String, required: true, 
     enum: {values: ['Administrator', 'Doctor','Patient','Optiker'], message: 
           '{VALUE} is not supported' }},
     image: {type: String},
     devices: [ {device: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Device"}} ]
    });
```

and I want to have something like this everytime i do a patch:

```
{
"user": {
    "_id": "6138cd30ffc5239bba72e6c0",
    "name": "Fernando",
    "lastname": "Gonzalez",
    "email": "f.gonzalez@unitransferklinik.de",
    "password": "Hol087+/*",
    "userTyp": "Administrator",
    "image": "sdsadsadsa/asdfasdas",
    "devices": [
        {
            "device": "6138c7587ab4b5fc4d369230"
        },
        {
            "device": "6138c7587ab4b5fc4d365210"
        }
    ],
    }
}
```

How can I implement in my function:

```
const updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
const { name, lastname, email, password, userTyp, device } = req.body;
    const userID = req.params.userID;
    let updatedUser;
    try {
        updatedUser = await User.findById(userID);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return next(new HttpError('Something happend.', 500));
    }

    updatedUser.name = name;
    updatedUser.devices = [device, ...updatedUser.devices];
    try{
             updatedUser.save();
        }catch (err) {
            return next(new HttpError('It could not uodate device.', 500));
        }
    });

    res.status(200).json({user: updatedUser.toObject( {getters: true} )});
};
```

In easy words, I want to updated the list everytime that i do a patch with a new device, and I can fetch later all the device list per user.

Thanks a lot!
regards,
Eliot

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOneAndUpdate function of mongoose library

```
const dynamicModel = libMongoose.model(collection_name, userSchema);
var filter = { userID: req.params.userID };
var update = { name: name, devices : [...device, ...updatedUser.devices]};
//callback approach
dynamicModel.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, (err, resp) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error while updating record " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    if(!resp) {
        console.log("Couldn't find record");
    } else {
        console.log("Updated data to DB");
    }
});
```

You can also refer [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) for async await, Hope this helps!